# SecAst: Potential documentation issue, Ubutunu 12.04.4 LTS and the command: cp -v

Tags: security, ubuntu-12.04, installation, asterisk, cp

To Generation D:

I am writing you about what might just be a documentation issue which hopefully doesn't have significant repercussions.

This is something I encountered immediately at the start on the first page of the installation process (page 7, section 2.1.3), with the first cases I was supposed to execute the command: cp -v

As I understand it, the switch -v is supposed to cause cp give "verbose" output, and should be synonymous with the switch: --verbose

HOWEVER, this is what I get when using it:

```
# cp –v geoip.db /usr/local/secast/
cp: cannot stat `–v': No such file or directory
```

and

```
# cp –-verbose geoip.db /usr/local/secast/
cp: cannot stat `–-verbose': No such file or directory
```

If I drop the -v or --verbose switch, the copy occurs as expected without any error message. (This is how I got through the rest of the installation process.)

I have not discovered why this is happening. I know that cp is /bin/cp and that it is not an alias.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.4 Server LTS x86_64 with the latest updates.

You mentioned that you were trying SecAst on Ubuntu 12. Do you experience this problem on your Ubuntu 12 installation?

** UPDATE **

The output of the alias command:

```
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias l='ls -CF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

** UPDATE 2 **

The output of 'which cp':

```
/bin/cp
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a Ubuntu 12 64bit installation and the -v parameters seems to work fine:

```
root@ubuntu:~# cd /tmp
root@ubuntu:/tmp# touch testfile
root@ubuntu:/tmp# cp -v testfile testfile2
'testfile' -> 'testfile2'
root@ubuntu:/tmp#
```

and it seems to work equally well on Red Hat 6.  I'm wondering if there is something else going on in your shell.  Can you post the output of the command 'alias' ?

Comment: Please see the update to the question above, which gives the output of 'alias' as requested.

Comment: hmm...how about 'which cp' output?

Comment: Please see the second update to the question above, which gives the output of 'which cp' as requested.

Comment: Well I'm scratching my head.  I would suggest you reword your question to be ubuntu specific (ignore Secast), change the tags to 'bash', 'ubuntu', 'cp', and change the title to include ubuntu and bash.  There's something in your shell that is fishy...

Answer (score 0):

The comments below all support that this is not SecAst related, something else is going wrong on your computer. Have a look at:

[Insufficient memory causing issues](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75054/ldd-tells-me-my-app-is-not-a-dynamic-executable)

The BASH issues (and LDD issues from your other post) all could be memory related, or a bad install of Linux....nothing SecAst related.